# Thread-safe but fast access to an "eventually final" variable?

Tags: java, synchronization, java-memory-model

I have a server somewhat like this:

```
class Server {

    private WorkingThing worker;

    public void init() {
         runInNewThread({
             // this will take about a minute
             worker = new WorkingThing();
         });
    }

    public Response handleRequest(Request req) {
         if (worker == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Not inited yet");
         return worker.work(req);
    }

}
```

As you can see, there are threads handling requests and a thread initing the server. Requests can come in before initing has finished, therefore there is the check with an `IllegalStateException`.

Now, to make this thread safe (so request handler threads don't see a stale, `null`-valued, version of `worker` just after init), I'd have to make worker volatile, synchronize on it, or some such.

However, after the init has completed, `worker` won't ever change again, so it's effectively final. Therefore, it seems like any lock contention that may occur would be a waste. So, what's the most efficient thing I can do here?

Now I know it doesn't really matter in a practical sense (with all the heavy lifting of reading a network request, etc, what does a single lock matter?), but I'd like to know out of curiosity.

Comment: using `synchronized` keyword costs a lot of cycles. I think the best way would be to make the `worker` variable `static`. This way it will allocate a reserved space in the memory, and I think the threads will always look at that space. Just a thought, may not be correct.

Comment: Is the invocation of `worker.work(req)` thread safe?  I'm just asking to make sure that you only require to block calling threads until `worker` has been initialized.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ViktorSeifert Yes, once `worker` is there, it's thread-safe.

Comment: Why do you take requests before initialization is complete? Why not init and then start service? What happens to request that come before initialization is complete? Do they block?

Comment: I ask because threads there's a happens-before guarantee on `start()`-ing a thread; if you start service threads on a thread after it completes init(), you don't need another memory barrier.

Comment: @erickson That part is outside of my control. What happens is that multiple instances of the server are started and inited in sequence by a container, but this container only start accepting requests when all services have been inited. I want the first service to be able to accept requests as soon as it's ready, without having to wait for services started later. Therefore, I need to put the initing in its own thread, so the container will see all services as "inited" rather quickly. However, that then makes it possible that requests are received before a service has actually inited completely.

Comment: If a thread writes `worker`, then calls `start()` on another thread that reads `worker`, no further memory barrier is necessary. There's a happens-before relationship on `start()` so anything one thread does before starting another is visible to the second. Is that the case here?

Comment: @erickson I think all threads involved are from a pool and started before any of this code runs.

Comment: With your additional explanation and another look at the code, I think I understand the situation. And my comment above doesn't apply. It looks like your best bet here is `volatile`. It's fast and safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A note on volatile: marking a variable volatile is cheaper than using synchronization (it does not involve locks) and is generally cheap enough that you won't notice. In particular, on x86 architectures, reading a volatile variable does not cost more than reading a non-volatile variable. However writing to a volatile is more expensive and the fact that the variable is volatile might prevent some compiler optimisations.

So using volatile is probably the option that gives you the best performance/complexity ratio in your scenario.

You don't have that many alternatives. In the end it boils down to ensuring a safe publication of your worker. And safe publication idioms include:

- initialising the instance from a static initialiser
- marking the reference to the instance as final
- marking the reference to the instance as volatile
- synchronizing all accesses

In your case, only the last two options are available and using volatile is more efficient.

Comment: Oh, I thought that volatile was more or less syntactic sugar for "give this variable a lock and always synchronize on it when accessing this variable". Nice to know that is not so.

Comment: Note that the static initialization takes place in a synchronized block; that's how visibility (and other properties) is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the worker is **volatile**.

Because of two reason

1. if you don't declare it as volatile than due to reordering and visibility  effects 
   you could see non-null reference to incomplete constructed Worker Object. and thus you could 
   have undesirable effects. This would not be happen if you make your worker immutable using all 
   final variables.
2. In theory it could be possible that your main thread may not see non-null reference of your worker object for a long time. So avoid it.

So concluding if worker is immutable than also for point 2 you should make it volatile.
Always avoid unpredictable results. Declaring it volatile will take care of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple locking for the initial request:

```
public synchronized void init() {
    if(worker!=null) return;
    runInNewThread({
        synchronized(Server.this){
            worker = new WorkingThing();
            Server.this.notify();
        }
    });
    this.wait();
}

public Response handleRequest(Request req) {
    if (worker == null) synchronized(this) {
        this.wait();
    }
    return worker.work(req);
}
```

This works because there are synchronization points between accesses to worker.

Comment: Never wait outside a loop. If you miss the notification signal you could wait forever. And there might be more than one thread waiting => use notifyAll. And there is no point waiting at the end of init.

Comment: Argh, right - should be double-lock checking in the handleRequest synchronized(this) block.

Answer (score 0):

I'd conisder using ava.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference
if it is null, iether throw or wait and try again (if init is fast enough).